# match an IP against a regular expression with CIDR range

Tags: regex, ip, cidr

I will be given an IP and then i have a list of regular expressions i can match it again.
But i want to match it to see if it falls within a CIDR range.

Example:

```
i have the IP: 66.102.0.0
now i need to find out if it will match against 66.102.0.0/20
```

It is not so much to check if it is a real IP, as it always will be.
Is this possible at all?

This will be for use in a node.js program named haraka: http://haraka.github.io/manual/plugins/access.html

Comment: It's possible, but you might as well turn the IP address into bytes and use bitwise operator to check.

Comment: problem is it has to be a regex because the software i am using will only accept a regex

Comment: Please include that information in the question, along with the program name, and possibly link to documentation. Different regex engine may have different syntax/matching semantics.

Comment: updated.  It is a small app built in node.js called haraka. so the regex would be done in javascript